# Strange edge behaviour of surface plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

I would like to make surface plot of a function which is discontinuous at certain values in parameter space. It is near these discontinuities that the plot's coloring becomes incorrect, as shown in the picture below. How can I fix this?

[image]

My code is given below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def phase(mu_a, mu_b, t, gamma):
    theta = 0.5*np.arctan2(2*gamma, mu_b-mu_a)
    epsilon = 2*gamma**2/np.sqrt((mu_a-mu_b)**2+4*gamma**2)
    y1 = np.arccos(0.5/t*(-mu_a*np.sin(theta)**2 -mu_b*np.cos(theta)**2 - epsilon))
    y2 = np.arccos(0.5/t*(-mu_a*np.cos(theta)**2 -mu_b*np.sin(theta)**2 + epsilon))
    return y1+y2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-2.5, 2.5, 0.01)
Y = np.arange(-2.5, 2.5, 0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = phase(X, Y, 1, 0.6)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

surf.set_clim(1, 5)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to make all the arrays 1D, filter out the NaN values and then call `ax.plot_trisurf`:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def phase(mu_a, mu_b, t, gamma):
    theta = 0.5 * np.arctan2(2 * gamma, mu_b - mu_a)
    epsilon = 2 * gamma ** 2 / np.sqrt((mu_a - mu_b) ** 2 + 4 * gamma ** 2)
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        y1 = np.arccos(0.5 / t * (-mu_a * np.sin(theta) ** 2 - mu_b * np.cos(theta) ** 2 - epsilon))
        y2 = np.arccos(0.5 / t * (-mu_a * np.cos(theta) ** 2 - mu_b * np.sin(theta) ** 2 + epsilon))
    return y1 + y2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 200)
Y = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 200)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
X = X.ravel() # make the array 1D
Y = Y.ravel()
Z = phase(X, Y, 1, 0.6)
mask = ~np.isnan(Z) # select the indices of the valid values

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(X[mask], Y[mask], Z[mask], cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

surf.set_clim(1, 5)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

[image: calling plot_trisurf with non-nan values]

Some remarks:

- `plot_trisurf` will join the XY-values via triangles; this only works well if the domain is convex
- to make things draw quicker, less points could be used (the original used 500x500 points, the code here reduces that to 200x200
- calling `fig.gca(projection='3d')` has been deprecated; instead, you could call `fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')`
- the warnings for dividing by zero or using arccos out of range can be temporarily suppressed; that way the warning will still be visible for situations when such isn't expected behavior